# What are acceptable "relationships with referees"?

Tags: application, recommendation-letter

I am applying for a job and need to give referees, and their relationship with me. I am not sure how to phrase things. My referees are:

- A colleague in my department I publish with
- A previous boss in another university I still publish with
- Senior people in my field who I have not published with (yet)

None of those things seem formal enough! Is there standard phrases I should be using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps:

- Colleague from current university and active collaborator
- Former employer and active collaborator
- Respected senior colleague from same field

Comment: Thanks, those are some good suggestions! Seeing as this question perhaps doesn't have a single correct answer, I will just wait a while to see if anyone else replies.